# Rails has_many :through with :conditions . How do I create the associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through, has-many

I have the following models associated with has_many through with conditions.

(Note that `Membership` validates the presence of the `kind` attribute)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :founded_groups,
    :through => :memberships,
    :source  => :group,
    :class_name => 'Group'
    :conditions => {'memberships.kind' => 'founder'}
  has_many :joined_groups, ... # same as above, but the kind is 'member'
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :founders, ...        # these two mirror the User's
  has_many :regular_members, ... #
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :user_id
  validates_presence_of :club_id
  validates_presence_of :kind   # <-- attention here!

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
```

Rails seems to like the code above (at least it doesn't bark to it). But then this happens:

```
> user = User.create(...) # valid user
> club = Club.create(...) # valid club
> user.founded_clubs = [club]

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: kind can't be blank

> club.founders << user

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: kind can't be blank
```

I was assuming that rails would take the `{'memberships.kind' => 'founder'}` part of my code and use it when creating the association, but it doesn't seem to be the case. So the new membership's `kind` is blank, and that throws an error.

Is there an easy way to create the associations, without it being a complete pain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for sure:

```
> user = User.create(...) # valid user
> club = Club.create(...) # valid club
> user.memberships.create(:club_id => club.id, :kind => 'founder')
```

I'm not sure, but this may work:

```
> user.memberships.create(:club => club, :kind => 'founder')
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to find some kind of syntax that allowed me to create memberships given multiple elements - one club and two users, or one user and two clubs. It seems that I'll just have to loop over the "many" parts and create associations manually. Oh, well.